# When we swing a ball around in circle there is a centripetal force on the string but is there a torque also proudced in the string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

When a ball is swinging in a circular path the is a centripetal force that is provided by the tension in the string but because it is a circular motion is there a torque also proudced in the circular motion.If so how is the torque produced.What are the components that helps in producing the torque?.What is the direction of the torque produced?

Comment: My thinking is there is no torque produced in the particles of rope , we know $τ=\vec{R}  
 \times \vec{F}$ then Force $\vec{F}$ is acting towards the center ( acceleration towards center hence force is acting towards center and then $\vec{R} $ is also in the same direction hence the angle between them is 0 hence no torque is produced

Comment: I suggest you draw a free body diagram of the ball

Comment: What makes you think a torque is produced?

Answer (score 1):

If a ball is swinging in a circle at a constant rate, there is no torque. Torque is like acceleration. It makes the ball circle faster or slower.

Centripetal acceleration does not produce torque. Torque would come from a force in the direction the ball travels, speeding it up. Or in the opposite direction, slowing it down. Centripetal acceleration is perpendicular to the direction of travel. It does neither.

Answer (score 0):

There is no net torque because there is no angular acceleration. For a ball rotating at constant circular speed in a horizontal plane there are only two forces involved:  gravity and the tension in the string. The lines of action of both act through the COM of the ball and therefore create no torque about the COM.

The downward force of gravity is balanced by the upward vertical component of the tension in the string for a net vertical force of zero and no vertical acceleration. The unbalanced horizontal component of the tension in the string is the centripetal force causing the ball to accelerate towards the center thereby creating circular motion.

Hope this helps.